# Data transfer objects (DTO) pattern in Go

Tags: c#, go, design-patterns, dto, domain-model

Note: refers mostly to the development of HTTP APIs and web development in general.

In C# and Java, we have DTO pattern, in layman's terms, it's just a class that's "domain-specific" sometimes also called "view model" (sent over a network). So for example, our DTO for login would be something like `LoginParams` with username and password (only).

Or let's say `CreateUserRequest` that contains properties needed only for that specific operation(to create a user we don't need id for example), and a separate DTO for a response (`CreateUserResponse` or just `User`).

It's also used to hide certain properties from being serialized or because API model differs too much from our domain or data model.

So consider a model `User` with property like `hashed_password`, obviously, we don't want to return `hashed_password` to the client of our HTTP API, because it's something that only server should know about. So for that purpose, we have a separate class `UserDto` or `UserResponseModel` with properties we want to send to the API user.

Automapper and similar libraries are commonly used to simplify this process by mapping one object to another for us.

I've read somewhere that this pattern in Golang isn't present and it's generally wrong to apply C# and Java patterns to language like Go (??).

If that is true how do you separate your data models and/or domain models from your API models?

Comment: If the requirements of your app are best implemented by having two separate types, one for data manipulation and one for data presentation, then that's what you should do. But keep in mind that for something simple as hiding certain fields from the API you can use `-` in the json/xml tags to omit fields from the output.

Comment: In C# when using Newtonsoft.Json there's `[JsonIgnore]` or more universal `[IgnoreDataMember]` attribute. So I guess it's pretty similar to `-` go tag. But sometimes you need separate structures anyway, (example: protobuf + gRPC). Separate models for requests, that call some more complex functions on the backend, with API internal to the backend.

Comment: Probably the following answer will help in this manner: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43748751/golang-dtos-entities-and-mapping

Comment: For what it's worth I created https://github.com/lynchborg/automapper to lower the barrier for having separate models